# Javascript: Turn an two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

How do you turn an two dimensional array? In my case I have an array that contains the score a player has on a specific round of the game.

I have

```
var results = new Array();  
for(var i = 1;i<7;i++){  
results[i] = new Array;  
}
```

which I print out as such `results[round][player]`

How do I "turn" the array, so I can get the data like this: `results[player][round]`
(Without changing the definition of the results array)

Comment: Do you mean "How to switch the dimensions on a two dimensional array?" ?

Comment: Yep, I guess that's what I am looking for. Tried to search around, but was not sure how to put the words down :)